# BackColor переопределяется при каждом запуске

Tags: c#, winforms

делаю свою программу на winforms. разумеется, перерисовывал интерфейс, formborderstyle = none, все вытекающие в виде form1_mousedown с winapi для ее перемещения (возможно, дело именно в этом). у моей программы всего несколько цветов, они все темного оттенка, возьмем к примеру один backcolor - fromargb(52, 54, 53) - близко к черному. если запускать программу, то изначально у абсолютно любого контрола (кроме тех, что enabled = false) его классический светлый backcolor. я пробовал задавать backcolor на нужный и в form1(), и в form1_load, и там и там одновременно, однако это не помогает вообще. выглядит это как мерцание, потому как цвет со светлого резко меняется в черный, соответственно не обращать на это внимание нереально. странно, но цвет как бы не наследуется от формы (хотя если добавить новый контрол, его backcolor будет таким же, как и форма).
используемое winapi (для перемещения формы, а так же для ее сворачивания (создан свой minimizebox)):

```
    public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
    public const int HTCAPTION = 0x2;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
    private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, скорее всего, связана с тем, что вы используете функцию **WinAPI** для реализации перемещения формы (`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` и `HTCAPTION`). При выполнении этой операции, возможно, происходит перерисовка контролов, что приводит к мерцанию цвета фона.

Одним из способов решения этой проблемы может быть использование метода DoubleBuffered для вашей формы. Этот метод позволяет создать двойной буфер, что уменьшает мерцание при перерисовке контролов.

Вы можете установить свойство DoubleBuffered для вашей формы следующим образом:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Скорее всего, это должно Вам помочь.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. я согласен с тем, что дело, по-видимому, именно в winapi. однако двойная буфферизация не помогает (уже включена). через замедление видео у меня получилось споймать момент, за каждым контролом появляется светлая область (вероятнее всего, backcolor), а потом становится такой, как нужно.  посередине два разных label, сверху слева - label, справа сверху - две невидимые кнопки (того же цвета, что и панель, поверх которой они лежат). у панели таких изменений нет, поскольку она выключена (https://ibb.co/FVFLzw6)

Comment: я также подметил, что этот баг случается не всегда. конкретных условий для его выполнения нет, при первом запуске он может как возникнуть, так и нет. это может не происходить и пять запусков подряд, а на шестой все равно пролагает и будет такой неприятный визуальный эффект